# Displaying the Right Colours with Swift and iOS

Tags: swift, colors, ios-simulator

I'm having trouble rendering colours precisely with Swift for my iOS app.

I've defined the colour RGB(82, 165, 234) using the website [Coolors](https://coolors.co/), so I use ColorSync Utility to pick it and it tells me that it is sRGB(98, 181, 238).

I define the colour in Swift:

```
let BlueColour = UIColor(red: 98.0/255.0, green: 181.0/255.0, blue:238.0/255.0, alpha: 1);
```

However when I run the app in the Simulator, the view is a different shade of blue. When I pick the colour of the view using ColorSync Utility, it tells me that the colour of my view is sRGB(72, 179, 241).

I can see that the colour in the Simulator is different to the colour that I've chosen in Coolors.

BlueColour.cgColor is:

```
[<CGColorSpace 0x170027bc0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1; extended range)] ( 0.384314 0.709804 0.933333 1 )
```

How can I ensure that I render my desired colours accurately?

Comment: I believe you are talking about color space, which is a level deeper than UIColor. Look into CGColor.

Comment: I've added BlueColour.cgColor to my question - it says the color space is sRGB; does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the 'Digital Color Meter' utility initiating UIColor() with like values, i.e UIColor(displayP3Red:green:blue:alpha:)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This picked up the correct sRGB value and now the colours in the Simulator are identical. I'm not sure why ColorSync Utility showed a different value.